# Сортировка большого (5 ГБ) двоичного файла в Linux

Tags: linux, сортировка

Есть двоичный файл размером 5 ГБ, состоящий из блоков по 6 байт. Нужно произвести сортировку этих блоков для дальнейшего быстрого поиска.
Готовую утилиту найти не смог.

Какие будут мысли? Как лучше реализовать?

Столкнулся еще с такой проблемой. При сортировке нужно менять блоки местами, т.е. писать в файл поверх имеющихся данных. Пробовал реализовать на `PHP - fwrite()` сдвигает данные.

Comment: А блоки по 6 байт каждый в отдельной строке находится?

Comment: Написать свой сортировщик на любом подручном языке. Если файл не умещается в ОЗУ разбить его на части, отсортировать каждую часть и слить части по алгоритму сортировки слиянием. Либо посчитать по файлу статистику распределения значений, разбить файл на части по принципу записи в каждый из файлов-части данные из опеределенного диапазона, отсортировать каждый файл и просто записать их на выход друг за другом

Comment: Написать сортировку и запустить. Кстати, какую утилиту Вы искали? Никто же в мире не знает что у Вас там за записи и по каким полям Вам надо их сортировать.

Comment: @ИванГладуш Если сказано двоичный файл, то значит там нет никаких переводов кареток и никаких строк, просто 6 байтные блоки, поэтому файл в памяти делят просто по размеру блока

Comment: Сделайте файлу map в память и напустите qsort

Comment: Что значит "fwite сдвигает данные" куда и насколько он их сдвигает ? Вы же seek делаете ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26062165/4827341 , ссылка из первого ответа: https://github.com/pelotoncycle/bsort